# how do I select a column based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable called @status which I set before this select statement:

```
Select
ordr_num as num,
ordr_date as date,
ordr_ship_with as shipwith
From
order
where ordr_num = @ordrNum
```

I only want to select `ordr_ship_with` column if `@status <> 'Cancelled'`, otherwise I want to select null for shipwith.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: it is best to not store the entire word 'Cancelled' in a status column.  status can be a char(1) with values "C"=cancelled, "O"=open, "D"=deleted, "P"=processed, etc.

Comment: I agree. Or use a `TinyInt` field so you can have many more statuses and map using an enum in code.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
SELECT ordr_num as num, ordr_date as date, 
    CASE WHEN @status<>'Cancelled' THEN ordr_ship_with ELSE NULL END as shipwith 
FROM order 
WHERE ordr_num = @ordrNum
```

Comment: First of all thank you for this answer, helped me a lot. How can use the column returned by CASE WHEN on the WHERE condition? I tried to use AS T and try to access T within the WHERE section but without success. Thank you.

Comment: You have to re-type it, or nest this query and put the condition in the outer section. Sql is dumb that way sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Try this out

```
Select 
    ordr_num as num, 
    ordr_date as date, 
    CASE 
        WHEN @Status <> 'Cancelled' THEN ordr_ship_with 
        ELSE NULL END
    as shipwith 
From order 
where ordr_num = @ordrNum
```

Although I have a feeling that you STATUS is an actual column in the Order table. In that case, do this:

```
Select 
    ordr_num as num, 
    ordr_date as date, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Status <> 'Cancelled' THEN ordr_ship_with 
        ELSE NULL END
    as shipwith 
From order 
where ordr_num = @ordrNum
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Select
    ordr_num as num,
    ordr_date as date,
    CASE WHEN @status <> 'Cancelled' THEN ordr_ship_with ELSE NULL END as shipwith
From
    order where ordr_num = @ordrNum
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Case : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE     
 WHEN @status <> 'cancelled' THEN ordr_ship_with  
 ELSE null  
END AS shipwith, ... other fields
```