# select clause evaluates and return value from different columns of joined tables

Tags: sql

I'm pretty sure that this question was already answered before however I cannot search it properly. Please for support.

My question is the following:

I have two tables(A+B) that are joined. What I would like to do is to put a condition in the select clause that will return value from a column - either from A or B based on specific value that i evaluate.

For example

Select A.id, 
A.country, 
case city 
when A.city like '%York' then "value from A.city" 
else value from B.town
end 
from A, B where 
A.id=b.id

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I select a column based on condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368527/how-do-i-select-a-column-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code was pretty close

```
SELECT A.id,
       A.country,
       CASE
           WHEN A.city LIKE '%York' THEN A.city
           ELSE B.town
       END AS LOCATION
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id=b.id
```